# How to covert this objective c into swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://iminichrispy.com/Xcode/TextFromWeb.txt"];
    NSString *content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy error:nil];
    label.text = content;
```

I have tried the following

```
var url:NSURL = NSURL(string: "http://iminichrispy.com/Xcode/TextFromWeb.txt")

var content:NSString = NSString(contentsOfURL: url, encoding: NSStringEncodingDetectionAllowLossyKey, error: nil)

label.text = content
```

At nil I keep getting the error: "Extra argument 'error' in call"

Comment: why you add this slashes to comment explanation?)

Comment: I am using this site for the first time and wasn't sure how to separate my explanation from the code, so I used the way we all know how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `encoding` parameter is supposed to be an encoding (which is an integer), not conversion option (which is a string, so the types don't match):

```
var url:NSURL? = NSURL(string: "http://iminichrispy.com/Xcode/TextFromWeb.txt")

var content:NSString? = NSString(contentsOfURL: url!,
                                 encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding,
                                 error: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this:

```
       var e : NSError?
   let content : NSString = NSString(contentsOfURL:url, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding, error:&e)
```

nil value is not supposed to be there.

Comment: "nil value is not supposed to be there." not true. `nil` can be there